# System.Windows.Form.WebBrowser will not render svg

Tags: c#, html, com, svg

I can render the text, but cannot render the svg element.  When I save the html I am trying to render as a svg file, Internet Explorer will render the complete image the way it should, so I fairly confident my input data is ok.

here is where I launch the thread that starts the webbrowser

```
Browserinfo bi = new Browserinfo(height, width, rsltPath, stype);
bi.Temphtml = temphtml.Replace("\\", "/");
Thread webBrowseThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(PerformWebBrowseOp));
webBrowseThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
webBrowseThread.Start(bi);
```

bi.Temphtml is the file that I save the input data to. This is the way the file looks (with the guts removed)

```
   <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    ..svg data...
    </svg></body></html>
```

here is the actual code:

```
private void PerformWebBrowseOp(object obj)
{
    Browserinfo bi = (Browserinfo)obj;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bi.Width, bi.Height))
    {
        using (WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate("file:///"+bi.Temphtml);
            while (webBrowser.Document.Body == null)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }


            IHTMLDocument2 rawDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
            //rawDoc.write(sbody);
            IHTMLElement rawBody = rawDoc.body;
            IHTMLElementRender2 render = (IHTMLElementRender2)rawBody;

            Rectangle bitmapRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.Width, bi.Height);
            webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bitmapRect);


            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder qualityEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            var quality = (long)100;
            using (EncoderParameter ratio = new EncoderParameter(qualityEncoder, quality))
            {
                using (EncoderParameters codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
                {
                    codecParams.Param[0] = ratio;
                    ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
                    if (bi.ImgType == "jpg")
                    {
                        ici = GetImageEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ici = GetImageEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save(bi.SavePath, ici, codecParams);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ((AutoResetEvent)waithandle[0]).Set();
}
```

In the interest of keeping the discussion focused the following notes might be helpful:
I initially used Batik and had it working, but Java is not installed on our webserver and the boss refuses to install it.  Back to the drawing board!

I downloaded svg.dll, and got it partially working.  It will render part of the svg element, but doesn't render the text.

I think I'm missing an interface or should be calling a com object, but haven't any idea how or what to do.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you cant do it that way.  However you can do it with librsvg.  I've copied my code below which works on the png but does not for jpeg.  If anyone can see whats wrong with the jpeg part, please let me know.

The files you will need are:

```
freetype6.dll
intl.dll
libcairo-2.dll
libcroco-0.6-3.dll
libexpat-1.dll
libfontconfig-1.dll
libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
libgio-2.0-0.dll
libglib-2.0-0.dll
libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
libgobject-2.0-0.dll
libgthread-2.0-0.dll
libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll
libpango-1.0-0.dll
libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll
libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
libpixbufloader-svg.dll
libpng14-14.dll
librsvg-2-2.dll
libxml2-2.dll
zlib1.dll
```

The extract of the svg code from your html page should look like this.

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="945" height="325"....</svg>

In other words, get rid of all the html except what is in the svg tags

here is the C# routine

```
private void RasterizeSvg(string tempsvg, string rsltPath, int _width, int _height, string formattype)
{
    string slib = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LibrSvgPath"];
    if (slib == null)
    {
        slib = @"C:\Librsvg";
    }
    bool callSuccessful = SetDllDirectory(slib); 
    if (!callSuccessful)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not set DLL directory");
    }

    // g_type_init is critical for the png to save correctly
    g_type_init();
    rsvg_init();

    IntPtr error = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr rsvghandle = rsvg_handle_new_from_file(tempsvg, out error);

    if (error != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Exception(Marshal.ReadInt32(error).ToString());
    }
    rsvg_handle_close(rsvghandle, out error);
    if (error != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Exception(Marshal.ReadInt32(error).ToString());
    }
    IntPtr cairosurface = cairo_image_surface_create(cairo_format_t.CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, _width, _height);
    IntPtr cairocontext = cairo_create(cairosurface);
    bool brslt = rsvg_handle_render_cairo(rsvghandle, cairocontext);

    cairo_destroy(cairocontext);

    if (formattype == "png")
    {
        cairo_surface_write_to_png(cairosurface, rsltPath);
        cairo_surface_destroy(cairosurface);
    }
    else
    {
        //jpeg not working.  the problem is how to convert from a cairo surface to a pixbuf
        // once we figure that out, we can implement the jpeg conversion

        /*option 1*/
        //IntPtr pixbuf = cairo_create(cairosurface);
        //cairo_set_source_surface(pixbuf, cairosurface, 0, 0);
        //cairo_rectangle(pixbuf, 0, 0, _width, _height);
        //cairo_fill(pixbuf);
        //error = IntPtr.Zero;                

        /*option 2*/
        IntPtr pixbuf = rsvg_handle_get_pixbuf(rsvghandle);
        rsvg_handle_close(rsvghandle, out error);

        cairo_surface_destroy(cairosurface);
        gdk_init(0, "");
        callSuccessful = gdk_pixbuf_save(pixbuf, rsltPath, formattype, out error);
        gdk_exit(out error);

        if (!callSuccessful)
        {
            throw new Exception(error.ToInt32().ToString());
        }
        /* need to release pixbuf memory*/
    }
    g_object_unref(rsvghandle);
}
```

As I said at the top, the jpeg doesnt work yet.  But it will render out to png.

Finally here are some declarations you will need

```
enum cairo_format_t
{
    CAIRO_FORMAT_INVALID = -1,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32 = 0,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24 = 1,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_A8 = 2,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_A1 = 3,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB16_565 = 4,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB30 = 5
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string pathname);

[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void g_type_init();

[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void g_object_unref(IntPtr obj);

[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern bool rsvg_handle_render_cairo(IntPtr handle, IntPtr cairorenderer);

[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr rsvg_handle_get_pixbuf(IntPtr _rsvghandle);

[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr rsvg_handle_new_from_file(string file_name, out IntPtr error);

[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern bool rsvg_handle_close(IntPtr _rsvghandle, out IntPtr error);

[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void rsvg_init();

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr cairo_create(IntPtr cairo_surface_t);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr cairo_image_surface_create(cairo_format_t _pixformat, int width, int height);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_surface_write_to_png(IntPtr cairo_surface_t, string filename);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_set_source_surface(IntPtr destbuf, IntPtr srcsuface, double x, double y);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_rectangle(IntPtr buf, double x, double y, double width, double height);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_fill(IntPtr destbuf);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_destroy(IntPtr buf);

[DllImport("libcairo-2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void cairo_surface_destroy(IntPtr buf);

[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern bool gdk_pixbuf_save(IntPtr pixbuf, string filename, string type, out IntPtr error);

[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, IntPtr cmap, int srcx, int srcy, int destx, int desty, int width, int height);

[DllImport("libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void gdk_init(int argcnt, string args);

[DllImport("libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void gdk_exit(out IntPtr error);
```